# Abelian centralizer groups (CA-groups)

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

I am searching for all information about CA-groups [abelian centralizer groups] and i just found a German book [Huppert] and Nilpotent Centralizer group of Suzuki in 44 pages and Group theory book of Suzuki.

I need more English books and thesis or journal having this title. Where can i find this?

Comment: There is a book called " Representations and Characters of Finite Groups" by Michael J. Collins ( Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics), which does much of the necessary character theory.

Comment: A definition would help. Also is it a specific interest on finite groups (as suggested by the tag?) please edit.

Comment: @YCor I think that CA-groups are the finite group theorists' terminology for commutative-transitive, but I agree that it would be good if the questioner could clarify this

Comment: In  a CA-group, the centralizer of every non-identity element is Abelian (the term is used by finite group theorists, though I suppose it could be used for infinite groups- but a Tarski monster would then be a CA-group, for example). Likewise, a CN-group is one in which the centralizer of each non-identity element is nilpotent). M. Suzuki proved that a non-Abelian simple (finite) CA-group has even order, and W. Feit, M. Hall and J.G. Thompson later proved that a non-Abelian simple finite CN-group has even order.

Comment: @YCor: In the above, by Tarski monster, I mean an infinite group in which every proper subgroup has order $p$, for some fixed prime $p$.